# Cannot open app on simulator because temp file is not created

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator

I am trying to build my app and deploy it to a simulator. When I click the build button, the app builds and the simulator launches. Right after it launches, I get an error saying `The operation couldn't be completed. (LaunchServicesError error 0.)`

In `~/Library/Logs/CoreSimulator/CoreSimulator.log`, the error is:

```
com.apple.dt.Xcode[34376] <Error>: Error Domain=LaunchServicesError Code=0 
"The operation couldn’t be completed. (LaunchServicesError error 0.)" 
UserInfo=xxx {Error=PackageExtractionFailed, ErrorDescription=Failed to copy 
file://~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MYAPP-xxx/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/MYAPP.app/ 
to file://~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/SIMULATOR-ID/data/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.DoYgL4/extracted/MYAPP.app/}
```

In `~/Library/Logs/CoreSimulator/SIMULATOR-ID/system.log`, the first error is:

```
open on ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MYAPP-xxx/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/MYAPP.app/.xxx.cls: Permission denied
```

It does not seem like the "temp.DoYgL4" folder is being created, and I must need to change the permissions somewhere. Which permissions do I need to change?

Comment: Have you tried to clean the build folder? Go to Product and press down ALT and then click "Clean build folder"

Comment: Yes, I have tried that and also have tried Simulator -> Reset Content and Settings.